# a good assistant uses their skills to help the master focus on their skills

Tags: singular-they

I have seen this sentence in [lots of websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20good%20assistant%20uses%20their%20skills%20to%20help%20the%20master%20focus%20on%20their%20skills%22&oq=%22a%20good%20assistant%20uses%20their%20skills%20to%20help%20the%20master%20focus%20on%20their%20skills%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3090j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=121&ie=UTF-8) and I'm really confusing about it:

> a good assistant uses their skills to help the master focus on their skills

When `A good assistant` is singular, why it says `their skills` while `their` is plural. It's the same for `master` and `their skills`.

I'm wondering if it is a grammatical mistake which lots of people are doing their websites, or a type of exception which I'm not aware about it.

I'm now confused about the real meaning of this sentence.

Comment: See http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/2790/3281. I also answered a similar question once. See http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/16612/3281.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question (+1) as it confuses many.

When the first noun is epicene, the following noun can take pronoun 'they'. It's a common practice.

For example:

> A client comes to you and does not find your website user-friendly, **they** will never come back.

A *client* serves as an epicene.

Useful reading about *[singular they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they)* will also help you understand it better.

Comment: See also: [They Instead of His or Her](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus) and [Gender Neutral Singular Pronoun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)